# Using R (and dplyr) to create multiple summary tables with factor information

Tags: r, summary

I'm an R beginner and am trying to take tables that look like this

```
ID Type
X  A
X  A
X  B
Y  C
Y  D
Y  E
Z  F
Z  F
```

And create summary tables for each ID value so they'll look like this

```
X  Y  Z  
A  C  F
B  D
   E
```

How would I go about doing this with dplyr or something similar? I've tried doing something like a crosstab, but since there are no numberic values I haven't been able to.

Comment: Do you want the unique values or the counts in your "summarized table"?

Comment: The unique values as I'll be using them to create data validation tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach using `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  distinct(ID, Type) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rn, names_from = ID, values_from = Type) %>%
  replace(., is.na(.), " ") %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  select(-rn)
```

**Output**

```
  X Y Z
1 A C F
2 B D  
3   E
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c('X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z'),
  Type = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'F'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Perfect! That worked great. I couldn't get it to run on my R/RStudio application on my desktop. I kept getting an error that pivot_wider could not be found (running R 3.5.3), but ran it on rstudio cloud on R3.6 and it ran perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear. Note that `pivot_wider` requires `tidyr` >= version 1.0.0 of the `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to download the "Psych" Package and use the "describeBy()" function.

```
id = c("X", "X", "X","Y","Y","Y","Z","Z")
type = c("A","A","B","C","D","E","F","F")
df = as.data.frame(id,type)

library("psych")

describeBy(df, group = id)
```

hope this helps.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.9.12.31/topics/describeBy

Answer (score 0):

We can get the `unique` values in `Type` for each `ID` and bind the data together using `rowr::cbind.fill` filling the missing values with empty string.

```
setNames(do.call(rowr::cbind.fill, c(by(df$Type, df$ID, unique), fill = "")), 
         unique(df$ID))

#  X Y Z
#1 A C F
#2 B D  
#3   E
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z"), 
Type = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "F")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```